# Run script via terminal and not be able to see code - Python

Tags: python

Hey I want people who download my python script to be able to run it via terminal, but not be able to see code of it. How to???

Answer (score 0):

You could compile it with Cython. This gonna generate C code then you can compile it with any C compiler such as GCC.